# QBitNinjaClient получение баланса c#

Tags: bitcoin

Создал кошелек, сгенерировал 5 адресов :

```
1KmjtM8aibtBqbPiJahYYEwcEAH2Duk9QH
1HV55k5erZrFA3SirFLULf1rTs4sKvvqQg
1B1Tx9wXVVmmySSDSFYekM7cy7xCTybEMg
1Py6rXFPepLa7nacuRhYsJWYcfFLYE6zkw
1GRHuGiHqtuLY3A6roH7fT9bjbbiG1foWM
```

На каждый из них перечислил деньги (не сразу, в течении n времени). Есть метод для проверки баланса :

```
    public static void GetBalance(string ssAddress, bool ssIsUnspentOnly, bool ssIsTestNet, out decimal ssBalance, out decimal ssConfirmedBalance)
    {
        Network net;
        if (ssIsTestNet)
            net = Network.TestNet;
        else
            net = Network.Main;
        QBitNinjaClient client = new QBitNinjaClient(net);
        var balance = client.GetBalance(new BitcoinPubKeyAddress(ssAddress), ssIsUnspentOnly).Result;
        ssBalance = 0.0M;
        ssConfirmedBalance = 0.0M;
        if (balance.Operations.Count > 0)
        {
            var unspentCoins = new List<Coin>();
            var unspentCoinsConfirmed = new List<Coin>();
            foreach (var operation in balance.Operations)
            {
                unspentCoins.AddRange(operation.ReceivedCoins.Select(coin => coin as Coin));
                if (operation.Confirmations > 0)
                    unspentCoinsConfirmed.AddRange(operation.ReceivedCoins.Select(coin => coin as Coin));
            }
            ssBalance = unspentCoins.Sum(x => x.Amount.ToDecimal(MoneyUnit.BTC));
            ssConfirmedBalance = unspentCoinsConfirmed.Sum(x => x.Amount.ToDecimal(MoneyUnit.BTC));
        }
    }
```

Использую так :

```
    decimal addressBalance = 0;
    decimal addressBalanceConfirmed = 0;
    GetBalance("1Py6rXFPepLa7nacuRhYsJWYcfFLYE6zkw", true, false, out addressBalance, out addressBalanceConfirmed);
```

Суть проблемы : на первых 3 кошельков баланс выдает верно, на остальных 2 выдает `0.0`, если быть точным, то выдает, что не было операций на этих счетах (`balance.Operations.Count =0`) Хотя [тык1](https://blockchain.info/tx/ffc21524760be4c4b3d4ede57d4189edac586b44dd7f62e446d1db341631d8e5), [тык2](https://blockchain.info/tx/54c41856a8b11ed9971f90f6fb3fb2ab7cc591860856db84cdd60112e37ba50d), что не так ?

Comment: Возможно недостаточно подтверждения на этих транзакциях? Сейчас показывает только 5, раньше требовалось 6 (не знаю как сейчас)

Comment: @Zergatul возвращает 2 значения, текущий баланс и подтвержденный баланс, когда посылал на первые 3 кошелька все показывало отдельно, сколько перечислил и сколько подтверждено, а сейчас не хочет. Если все же требует более 5, то можно как-то сократить кол-во подтверждений ?

Comment: Не могу подсказать, не работал с QBitNinjaClient

Comment: @Zergatul можете посоветовать ресурс для удобного просмотра информации по иду транзакции ? например, в xml виде

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду внешний ресурс, или локальное хранилище блокчейна?

Comment: @Zergatul внешний, сейчас остановился на blockexplorer

Comment: Пару лет назад я пользовался blockchain.info api https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

Comment: @Zergatul а как вы там определяли баланс ? в апи такой запрос: ru/balance?active=$address , но баланс показывает без разделителя, если на счет 2.2 бтц, то покажет 22, или, если на счет 0.22, то тоже покажет 22 и не понятно

Comment: Баланс пишется в сатоши, просто разделите число на 100 миллионов, и получите баланс в биткоинах

Comment: @Zergatul понял, спасибо. Не знаете, есть ли там какие-то ограничения ? скажем, не более 1к запросов с 1 ип в день и тп ? ибо в blockexplorer заметил, что не надолго банит, после нескольких десятков обращений

Comment: Ограничения есть, но я не знаю какие.